# Add/Remove Extjs combo value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am newbie to extjs.I need to add/remove some values from extjs combo box base on some condition.  I tried following code but no luck.

```
var obj =Ext.getCmp('filter');
                    var myArray=new Array();
                    myArray['id'] = 'a';
                    myArray['value'] = 'a';
                    var rec = new Ext.data.Record(myArray);
                    //obj.store.add(rec);

                    obj.store.removed(rec);
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getById to find record for remove.

```
var combo = Ext.getCmp('filter');
combo.store.remove(combo.store.getById('a')); //typo: sotre corrected to store
```

combo.store.remove(combo.store.getById('a'));

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.store.remove(rec);
```

removed is not a store function.

removed is a buffer array in which all removed recors are added.

if you're going to have a big store, you should keep this array empty, because removed objects are stored during all the session.

if the combo didn't change try to add store.sync() after adding or removing records

Comment: thanks for inputs.. How should I remove specific record from combo box? is any other alternative

Comment: You can use .removeAt(index) or .remove(specificRecord).

Comment: for specific record case you should create a record like this: var rec=Ext.create(store.getModel());   set values with function record.set(field,value). rate me if i'm useful <3

Comment: [link](http://docs.sencha.com) have a look here to know better which functions are avaiable.